# Java Script - Google charts

Tags: javascript

I am developing a dynamic google chart with asp.net , my problem is that when i pass Double values to google chart it parses the values to integer , even if the value is double , how can i view data as it is (double), here is my code

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
 'packages': ['bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Tunisia'],
  ['2012', 20.22, 640.52, 200],
  ['2013', 50.72, 150, 30.52]
 ]);
 var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Tunisia'],
  ['2012', 30, 100, 100],
  ['2013', 120, 80, 20]
 ]);
 var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Tunisia'],
  ['2012', 180, 200, 70],
  ['2013', 170, 60, 190]
 ]);
 var options2 = {
  chart: {
   title: 'jordan -mk3',
   subtitle: 'jordan -mk3 2012-2013',
   backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  bars: 'vertical',
  vAxis: {
   format: 'decimal'
  },
  chartArea: {
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  height: 400,
  backgroundColor: {
   fill: null
  },
  colors: ['#004389', '#AA2121', '#3C3C3C', '#3C3C3C', '#d95f02']
 };
 var options1 = {
  chart: {
   title: 'jordan -mk2',
   subtitle: 'jordan -mk2 2012-2013',
   backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  bars: 'vertical',
  vAxis: {
   format: 'decimal'
  },
  chartArea: {
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  height: 400,
  backgroundColor: {
   fill: null
  },
  colors: ['#004389', '#AA2121', '#3C3C3C', '#3C3C3C', '#d95f02']
 };
 var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
 chart2.draw(data2, options2);
 var options3 = {
  chart: {
   title: 'jordan -mk4',
   subtitle: 'jordan -mk4 2012-2013',
   backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  bars: 'vertical',
  vAxis: {
   format: 'decimal'
  },
  chartArea: {
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  height: 400,
  backgroundColor: {
   fill: null
  },
  colors: ['#004389', '#AA2121', '#3C3C3C', '#3C3C3C', '#d95f02']
 };
 var chart3 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
 chart3.draw(data3, options3);
 var options = {
  chart: {
   title: 'jordan -mk4',
   subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
  },
  bars: 'vertical',
  vAxis: {
   format: 'decimal'
  },
  height: 400,
  colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3', '#7570b3', '#d95f02']
 };
 var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
 chart.draw(data, options1);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
<div id="chart_div3"></div>
```

Comment: I believe you need to specify that you are going to use float or double numbers in your fields when you are writing them. 
I found an example and it shows the declaration like this:
`['Mike', {v:22500, f:'22,500'}], // Format as "22,500".
       ['Bob', 35000]`
You can find an example here: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable

Comment: that didnt work for me , i have solve it by adding this line of code chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options1))

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easy just to add this line of code `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options1));`
The code will be like:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Tunisia'],
        ['2012', 20.22, 40.52, 200],
        ['2013', 50.72, 150, 30.52]
    ]);
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Tunisia'],
        ['2012', 30, 100, 100],
        ['2013', 120, 80, 20]
    ]);
    var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Egypt', 'Morocco', 'Tunisia'],
        ['2012', 180, 200, 70],
        ['2013', 170, 60, 190]
    ]);
    var options2 = {
        chart: {
            title: 'jordan -mk3',
            subtitle: 'jordan -mk3 2012-2013',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
        bars: 'vertical',
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal'
        },
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        height: 400,
        backgroundColor: {
            fill: null
        },
        colors: ['#004389', '#AA2121', '#3C3C3C', '#3C3C3C', '#d95f02']
    };
    var options1 = {
        chart: {
            title: 'jordan -mk2',
            subtitle: 'jordan -mk2 2012-2013',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
        bars: 'vertical',
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal'
        },
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        height: 400,
        backgroundColor: {
            fill: null
        },
        colors: ['#004389', '#AA2121', '#3C3C3C', '#3C3C3C', '#d95f02']
    };
    var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart2.draw(data2, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options2));
    var options3 = {
        chart: {
            title: 'jordan -mk4',
            subtitle: 'jordan -mk4 2012-2013',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
        bars: 'vertical',
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal'
        },
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        height: 400,
        backgroundColor: {
            fill: null
        },
        colors: ['#004389', '#AA2121', '#3C3C3C', '#3C3C3C', '#d95f02']
    };
    var chart3 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
    chart3.draw(data3, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options3));
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'jordan -mk4',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
        },
        bars: 'vertical',
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal'
        },
        height: 400,
        colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3', '#7570b3', '#d95f02']
    };
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options1));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
<div id="chart_div3"></div>
```